# Extension of conditional probability result for non independent random vectors

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X$ & $Y$ be random vectors. Let $Z$=$f(X,Y)$ be a random variable.

Then if $X$ & $Y$ are independent, the following is a well known result:

$P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B)$

***I need some help to 'formalize' what appears to be an intuitive generalization when $X$ & $Y$ are not assumed to be independent, namely that***

$P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$

without assuming $Y$ is discrete.

One 'immediate' problem for example is that, I am not sure that the RHS of the above equation is well defined.

*Breiman's text 'Probability'*, defines the conditional probability $P(C\mid Y=y)$ (*Definition 4.7* ) as a measurable function in $y$ satisfying

$P(C, Y\in A )$=$\int_{A} P( C\mid Y=y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$ where $C$ is a measurable subset of the sample space and $A$ is an arbitrary Borel subset in the state space of $Y$.

***Using the concept of Regular Conditional Probability, I think the statement above can be formalized as follows.***

Let $X$ & $Y$ be random vectors. Let $Z$=$f(X,Y)$ be a random variable, and $P_{Y}$ be the marginal distribution of $Y$. Let $Q_{X\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$ be a regular conditional distribution for $X$ given $Y=y$.

Then $P(f(X,Y)\in B\mid Y=y)$  = $P(f(X,y)\in B\mid Y=y)$, is I believe an ***intuitive interpretation*** of the following 'unproven' statement

$Q_{Z\mid Y}( B\mid y)$= $Q_{X\mid Y}(B_y \mid y)$

where $B$ is any arbitrary Borel subset of $R$, and  $B_y$ = $[x \mid f(x,y) \in B]$

and $Q_{Z\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$ the regular conditional distribution for $Z=f(X,Y)$ given $Y=y$.

Written alternatively we need to prove that

$P(Z\in B, Y\in A )$=$\int_{A} Q_{Z\mid Y}( B\mid y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$=$\int_{A} Q_{X\mid Y}( B_y\mid y) \, P_{Y}(dy)$

So to conclude my question is how to prove the above statement about Regular Conditional Probabilities, and if the generalization to non independent vectors is correct.

***FYI I posted a similar question on MathStackExchange and have not got a response.***